# C# equivalent to shell_exec

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, shell-exec

How execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string using C#?

equivalent to [shell_exec()](http://php.net/shell_exec) of PHP.

Thanks,advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [MSDN documentation on Process.StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) documentation shows an example

```
// Start the child process.
Process p = new Process();
// Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
p.Start();
// Do not wait for the child process to exit before
// reading to the end of its redirected stream.
// p.WaitForExit();
// Read the output stream first and then wait.
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

You might like to extract the standard error stream as well.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Process class [Standard Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) and [Standard Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx), and the [OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) and 
[ErrorDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived.aspx) recieved events.

There is a [CodeProject article here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/launchprocess.aspx), which you may find helpful.